# Remove SMS notification on Lenovo A800

Tags: sms, notification-bar

How can I remove the SMS notification in status bar? I think I have no Notification setting.

Answer (score 0):

If Lenovo didn't change the stock messaging app: open `Messaging` and press the `Menu` in the down-right corner and choose `Settings`. Scroll down to the `Notifications` section and uncheck `Notifications`.

Comment: thank you sir..bt my LENOVO A800 dont have notification settings

Comment: @mickhagon Could you take a screenshot of the settings page?